# Is $ \forall\space x \in \mathbb{R} \space \exists \space y \in \mathbb{R} \space(x+y^2=10)$ true or false?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given the expression $\forall\space x \in \mathbb{R} \space \exists \space y \in \mathbb{R}\space(x+y^2=10)$ tell what is its logical value?

When I look to an expression with quantifiers, I try to translator into current language. In this case my atempt was "for each real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ that satisfy $x+y^2=10$". Or " for a given real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ that satisfy $x+y^2=10$".

Can I take from the previous thought that $y=\sqrt{10-x} \space$ ?(for a given $x$...there is a $y$).
Thanks

Comment: false, because when x=-11, there does not exist real $y$ such that it satisfies the equation

Comment: No, if you chose x to be greater then 10, no real number y will satisfy the equation.

Comment: @NgHongWai: How about $\sqrt{21}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false, as you won't find an appropriate $y$ for $x>10$.
If, however, you would allow $y$ to be a complex number, the statement would be true.

Concerning your translation. I agree with the first one, but

> "for a given real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ that satisfy $x+y^2=10$"

should rather be

> "for ANY given real number $x$ there is a real number $y$ that satisfy $x+y^2=10$"

even though your expression isn't wrong, but using "any" makes it more clear in my opinion.

Comment: I chose this, because it answer to my doubt. That was if my "translation" was the right one.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, there is no $y \in \mathbb{R}$ for $x>10$ which satisfies the equation

[image: Graph of $x+y^2=10]

Comment: Your answer gave me a geometric poin of view. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Suppose this is true. Then**   $ \ \ \ y^2 =10 - x \iff y = \sqrt{10-x} \iff 10-x\ge0 \iff x \le 10$ but that is a contradiction to *$x$ can be all real numbers.* $ \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \boxed{}$